# How to restore a RDS Postgres instance from a snapshot exported to S3?

Tags: postgresql, restore, amazon-rds

Amazon RDS Postgres database are backed up as snapshots automatically. Because of the high storage costs ($0.095 per GB-Month), I want to move them to S3 (Storage Class: Glacier Deep Archive: 0.00099 per GB-Month).

I basically followed this [excellent guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lyNGeDg6EII) on youtube to [export DB snapshot data to Amazon S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ExportSnapshot.html), which creates a file structure with parquet files per table.

Before I proceed, I want to make sure I'm able to restore those files in S3 as a new database instance again. I can't find options to do that within AWS. So my question is this.

How to restore a RDS Postgres instance from a snapshot exported to S3?

Answer (score 1):

I found this resource on aws for importing for Postgres from s3. Though it does not exactly restore. We have to do the work to restore. [Importing Amazon S3 data into an RDS for PostgreSQL DB instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_PostgreSQL.S3Import.html)

I wish it had something like it has for MySQL DB. You can restore the MySQL db instance itself. [restore-db-instance-from-s3](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/rds/restore-db-instance-from-s3.html)

Comment: Thank you. However they don't mention how the data on S3 should look like. Do they mean restoring whatever a pg_dump generated (either custom format or sql) or do they mean an RDS snapshot copied to S3?

Answer (score 0):

I'm still waiting for AWS to provide a full PG RDS restore from snapshot stored on S3.

at the moment this is the closest thing you can do, per table basis only.
https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/04/amazon-rds-postgresql-supports-data-import-from-amazon-s3/

Comment: Hi! Also was looking for the restore options from AWS. Have you found any better solution?

Comment: Also waiting for the same, similarly frustrated by AWS seemingly implying this would be like extra-cold storage for backups... anyway, in that YouTube video guide you watched, at around 4:30 it shows how to use Glue & Athena to query the parquet files in the "snapshot-export" on S3. It's not a solution, but it's a workaround in some cases, just FYI in case that would help you.